# Timer error java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, timer

The error message is `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` (at the line `timeOutControl.start()`). What might be the reason?

```
TimeOutControl timeOutControl = new TimeOutControl();

//...

timeOutControl.start();

  public class TimeOutControl extends Thread {

    public void run() 
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (CVRPTW.DO_IT) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > CVRPTW.maxruntime) {
                CVRPTW.DO_IT = false;
                break;
            }

            try {
                sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code for `TimeOutControl`.  There's not enough information here.

Comment: Seems like the call to `start()` is done twice in your code.

Comment: The exception is thrown in timecontrol.start(). Provide the code for that part.

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Comment: @Andrew Schuster: Please see the updated post.

Comment: @Little Child> Stacktrace provides this: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) for Thread.start() says:

> Throws:
>      IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

So the answer is that you're trying to start the same thread twice. If you must do that, then construct a new instance of TimeOutControl each time you want to start it.